# Threading pause issue

Tags: c#, multithreading

Okay, I'm working on a console app that does a bunch of fancy database handling that isn't particularly relevant, however I need the program to pause and wait on a FileSystemEventHandler event. Looking online I used the Thread.Sleep(10000) function for 10 seconds while it watches for a file to be moved (or deleted, it checks elsewhere later). The wait works, but here's the clincher. When a file is moved it performs a large amount of functions afterwards, however the original thread sleep keeps counting and ends the program even if it's still executing.

My problem seems to be that I've accidentally delved into the world of concurrency, when in fact I just want to hold on for a few seconds. So either I need to change my wait method or use some thread handling. Any suggestions?

Note: This program will be ran from a server and thus functions that require user input (i.e Console.ReadKey()) wont work as nobody will be there to end the program.

Here is the relevant section of code:

```
File.Move("XX" + filename); //Omitted the path name
//Now we watch if the file leaves. If it does, find it in the other directories.
csvwatch.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(csvwatch_Moved);//Watch for a deletion (move is a copy then delete)
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); //10000 = 10 seconds
```

(csvwatch_Moved if the function called upon file deletion)

Comment: What about using a simple flag / ManualResetEvent and wait for it to be set, i.e. do not exit until it is set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .Net 4.5, you can use the `async` and `await` as mentioned by Taha, you can make the `File.Move()` process asynchronous, once the move is completed, you can then perform the next job/function without sacrificing the responsiveness of your application. Sample code here:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Test();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static public async void Test() {
    Console.WriteLine("Will move...");
    await MoveAsync();

    //Will pause here while moving
    //Do next job here...
    Console.WriteLine("Move was completed. On to next job!!");
}

static public async Task MoveAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() => Move());
}

static public void Move()
{
    //Do moving of file here....

    //System.IO.File.Move()
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); // Simulate moving...

    //Completed?
    Console.WriteLine("Moved.");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `async` methods with `await`. **If you  can't**, you can check a flag variable in an endless loop, when your condition is satisfied you can break the loop. This way you don't need to know how much you have to wait.

Comment: That would do it, I can't believe I jumped to thread handling before a loop break! Such an engineers way of thinking :p

Although, thanks for introducing me to async and await, they look like very interesting concepts I should learn :)

Comment: Oh please don't check a variable in a loop. There are threading issues even if reading an atomic value. There are proper ways to pause a thread.

Comment: :) You can use @Joel Legaspi Enriquez 's example for `async/await`. The problem with endless loop is, it is hard to control if the flag variable is assigned correctly. And if it's not, it is hard to debug. Using `async/await` pattern is a better practice.